# swap elements in a linked list without access to it?

Tags: c, linked-list

if i have a reference to an element in a linked list, how do i swap it with the next element, in c

here's a try,

```
Node* nRoot, *temp=pNode->next;
        nRoot=pNode;
        do{
            nRoot->next = temp->next;
            if(nRoot==pNode) pNode=temp;
            temp->next = nRoot;
            nRoot=nRoot->next;

        }while(nRoot!=NULL)||temp!=NULL);
```

but it does not work

Comment: singly linked list? Sounds like homework...

Comment: i added some code, i tried, but still cant get it

Comment: If you have access to the data in the node, you could possibly swap that.

Comment: Is this a trick question? I've seen people trying to look smart (teachers and such) pose the challenge, intending for the solution to be swapping the *contents* of the nodes rather than the nodes. Of course this is not a solution to the actual problem, because now all external references to either of the "swapped" nodes in the list will reference the wrong data.

Comment: @R that's incorrect. The external references to the nodes will be the same as they were before. They won't be pointing the the same data, but that's okay because they shouldn't be pointing to the same data, but rather the swapped data.

Comment: You're confusing swapping identities with swapping position in the list. If you just want to swap the position of two objects in the list, that should not cause external pointers to point to different objects from what they pointed to before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do this if it double linked list.  You need the previous pointer so that you can point it's next to the current's next.

However if you have these then you an do something like this:

```
Node* next       = curr->next;
Nide* prev       = curr->prev;
curr->prev       = next;
curr->next       = next->next;
curr->next->prev = curr;
next->prev       = prev;
next->prev->next = next;
next->next       = curr;
```

And the 2 are swapped.

Edit: Of course you can do this with a singly linked list but you do need to know the previous node so that you fix up its next pointer to point to the current's next.

Comment: Technically you can still do it with a SLL if you have a reference to the head of the linked list.

Comment: I do have a reference to the head of the list, void function(LinkedList* ll, Node* node)

Comment: I won't -1, but you do not need to know the previous node.

Comment: @JMoney38:  Having the head of the list just gives you the ability to find the previous node ...

Comment: @glowcoder: I think R.. explains the problem with swapping the data best.  I wouldn't call swapping data swapping elements though ...

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reference to A and A->next is B, you can do this. I'm assuming they hold a Data* pointer, replace with whatever the data is. Don't actually swap the nodes, just swap the data in the nodes.

```
void push_forward(Node* curr) 
{
    Data* currData = curr->data;
    curr->data = curr->next->data;
    curr->next->data = currData; 
}
```

For the record, **I am not a C guy** so this might be correct only in algorithm, but not in implementation. I welcome edits, fixes, suggestions, and constructive comments!

Comment: I am a C guy and the code looks fine.  Except I might add a null check beforehand however.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

If there are no external pointers to the elements that you wish to swap, then you can just swap the data within the list nodes, rather than the nodes themselves, as pointed out in other answers.

If you have external pointers to the list nodes, then you should probably not mess with the node content, unless the rest of your program is find with node contents changing from under its feet.

You will have to swap the nodes, which means that you need to have a pointer to the node that precedes the ones that you need to swap. If you only have the head of the list, then the swap function could be something along these lines:

```
void swap(Node **list, Node *first) {
    Node *i = *list;
    Node *p = NULL;

    while (i != NULL) {
        if (i == first) {
            Node *n = i->next;

            /* No next node to swap with */
            if (n == NULL)
                break;

            if (p != NULL) {
                p->next = n;
            } else {
                *list = n;
            }

            i->next = n->next;
            n->next = i;

            break;
        }

        p = i;
        i = i->next;
    }
}
```